# apollonian circles: why are radius and center dual?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, sangaku

This figure suggests the radii and centers (regarded as complex numbers) of the Soddy circles satisfy the same equation:
$$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = \frac{1}{2} (a + b + c + d)^2$$ 
How can the circle and radius be dual in this particular sangaku problem?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17949100/soddy.png

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.  Are you asking for a proof of that equation (for both centers and radii)?  Have you looked at "Wilks et al."?

Comment: @HewWolff, two articles on Apollonian circles in the present Bulletin, see link in my "answer." Hmmm, one P, two L's

Comment: The link is dead, could you insert the image in the question?

Comment: @cactus314 could you enclosed the figure?

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are two new articles on Apollonian packings, downloadable for free, at [BULLETIN](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2013-50-02/)

Both bibliographies list four articles, from 2003 to 2006, by Ronald L. Graham, Jeffrey C. Lagarias, Colin L. Mallows, Allan R. Wilks, and Catherine H. Yan. All four titles begin *Apollonian circle packings:* as mentioned by Hew Wolff